# Desabilitar o GPS via código no Android 4.2 para cima?

Tags: android, gps

Como posso desabilitar o GPS via código, sem intervenção do usuário?

Comment: Não é  possível ligar/desligar o Gps sem o conhecimento do utilizador.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta essa estratégia, funcionou comigo a algum tempo atrás no projeto que estava, não lembro a versão que usei do Android - só tinha esse trecho salvo para backup.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", false);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela respostas, mas este código da permissão negada do Android.